# Converting Python tf code to C++

Tags: arduino, c++, rosserial, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any non-trivial examples for using the tf package to calculate quaternions in C++ for an Arduino?

I'm trying to convert this Python code for publishing IMU data, to the equivalent C++, so I can run it on an Arduino using the rosserial_arduino package:

```
import rospy
import tf
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu
from std_msgs.msg import Header

imu_msg = Imu()
imu_msg.header = Header()
imu_msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
imu_msg.header.frame_id = '/base_link'
quaternion = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(roll, pitch, yaw)
imu_msg.orientation.x = quaternion[0]
imu_msg.orientation.y = quaternion[1]
imu_msg.orientation.z = quaternion[2]
imu_msg.orientation.w = quaternion[3]
imu_msg.linear_acceleration.x = accel[0]
imu_msg.linear_acceleration.y = accel[1]
imu_msg.linear_acceleration.z = accel[2]
imu_pub.publish(imu_msg)
```

However, even though there are several [general-purpose C++ examples](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) and rosserial_arduino examples [for using Tf](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Time%20and%20TF), I can't find anything for calculating quaternions on the Arduino.

All the C++ code I've found seems to require defining:

```
tf::Transform transform;
```

However, there doesn't seem to be any tf.h header available for the Arduino, and this gives me the compilation error:

```
error: 'Transform' in namespace 'tf' does not name a type
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258425/converting-python-tf-code-to-c++/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-04-02**:
my 2 cents: I always try to do as little on the arduino as possible, in you case, I'd send the data you read on the serial connection and then handle the conversions on a system where you just have all the libraries (and python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems quaternions and IMU message sending work just fine on the Arduino, but some of the tf math is missing. Rosserial only implements `createQuaternionFromYaw`, but I need `createQuaternionFromRPY`. Fortunately, this algorithm is well documented elsewhere, as the [rosserial_arduino author noted](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/84#issuecomment-290981349), so all I had to add to my code was:

```
static geometry_msgs::Quaternion createQuaternionFromRPY(double roll, double pitch, double yaw) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Source_Code
    // http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Quaternion.html
    geometry_msgs::Quaternion q;
    double t0 = cos(yaw * 0.5);
    double t1 = sin(yaw * 0.5);
    double t2 = cos(roll * 0.5);
    double t3 = sin(roll * 0.5);
    double t4 = cos(pitch * 0.5);
    double t5 = sin(pitch * 0.5);
    q.w = t0 * t2 * t4 + t1 * t3 * t5;
    q.x = t0 * t3 * t4 - t1 * t2 * t5;
    q.y = t0 * t2 * t5 + t1 * t3 * t4;
    q.z = t1 * t2 * t4 - t0 * t3 * t5;
    return q;
}
```

and then my IMU publisher looks like:

```
imu_msg.header.stamp = nh.now();
imu_msg.header.frame_id = base_link;
imu_msg.orientation = createQuaternionFromRPY(imu.roll_radians, imu.pitch_radians, imu.yaw_radians);
imu_msg.linear_acceleration.x = imu.accel.x;
imu_msg.linear_acceleration.y = imu.accel.y;
imu_msg.linear_acceleration.z = imu.accel.z;
imu_publisher.publish(&imu_msg);
```

I ran into some weird issues because I forgot to advertise my publisher with:

```
ros::Publisher imu_publisher = ros::Publisher("imu", &imu_msg);
```

and I think that was causing the Arduino to crash or hang, and I was confusing that with the IMU packet being too big, when it was actually just fine. But after I added that, I was able to subscribe to `/myarduino/imu` with rostopic and see IMU messages stream without issue.

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2017-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1